# Awk transpose data with multi field separators

Tags: awk

I'm trying to do the following with just one awk command.
I have a text file with the following structure

###### File fields description (not in file)

First fields are separated with ":", last field (host list) separated by spaces
Uniq id:Name:Uniq identifier:host_list (may be empty to many and can be repeated)

###### File content

```
sv_0:blabla:205700DD4C506261796ED3:Host_10 Host_1 Host_16
sv_111:abcd:205700DD4C50629585735C:Host_10
sv_3:xpto1:2057008E714F629B3BCDCF:Host_11 Host_10
sv_46:something:205700DD4C50629E5AB93A:
```

###### Need to convert this input to this output

```
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_10
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_1
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_16
sv_111 abcd 205700DD4C50629585735C Host_10
sv_3 xpto1 2057008E714F629B3BCDCF Host_11
sv_3 xpto1 2057008E714F629B3BCDCF Host_10
sv_46 something 205700DD4C50629E5AB93A
```

Using the next command works, but I don't like to use pipe after pipe

`awk -F: '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4 }' file.txt | awk '{nfield=4; while (NF >= nfield) {print $1" "$2" "$3" "$nfield; nfield++}}'`

Comment: can any of the first 3 fields contain spaces? if the answer is 'yes' then please update the question with an example (input + expected output)

Comment: no, the first 3 fields never have spaces.

Answer (score 6):

With single `gawk` command:

```
awk -F'[: ]' '{ for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$3,$i }' file.txt
```

---

```
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_10
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_1
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_16
sv_111 abcd 205700DD4C50629585735C Host_10
sv_3 xpto1 2057008E714F629B3BCDCF Host_11
sv_3 xpto1 2057008E714F629B3BCDCF Host_10
sv_46 something 205700DD4C50629E5AB93A
```

Comment: Multi separators, always learning :)

Comment: FYI that'll work in any awk, not just gawk.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to just consider the initial field-separator as a space, take the first part of `$1` up to `"Host_10"` as a prefix and then output each of the fields appending the prefix to fields `2`->`NF`, e.g.

```bash
awk '{
  gsub(/:/," ",$1)                # replace field-1 ":" to " "
  pfx=$1                          # save field-1 as prefix
  sub(/ [^ ]+$/,"",pfx)           # remove Host_x from end of prefix
  print $1                        # output full field-1
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)              # loop over remaining fields
    print pfx" "$i                # output prefix and field
  }
' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in file `dat/hostdata.txt` you would have:

```
$ awk '{
>   gsub(/:/," ",$1)                # replace field-1 ":" to " "
>   pfx=$1                          # save field-1 as prefix
>   sub(/ [^ ]+$/,"",pfx)           # remove Host_x from end of prefix
>   print $1                        # output full field-1
>   for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)              # loop over remaining fields
>     print pfx" "$i                # output prefix and field
>   }
> ' dat/hostdata.txt
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_10
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_1
sv_0 blabla 205700DD4C506261796ED3 Host_16
sv_111 abcd 205700DD4C50629585735C Host_10
sv_3 xpto1 2057008E714F629B3BCDCF Host_11
sv_3 xpto1 2057008E714F629B3BCDCF Host_10
sv_46 something 205700DD4C50629E5AB93A
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Very nice and detailed answer, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you sir. More that one way to skin-the-cat with `awk`!

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk` in your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Use regex in `match` function and using regex there to create 2 capturing groups into array arr.

```
awk '
match($0,/^(.*):(.*)$/,arr){
  gsub(/ /,ORS arr[1] OFS,arr[2])
  print arr[1] (arr[2]?OFS arr[2]:"")
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: I like it. Good to see your use of `match()` and note of the GNU awk `arr` extension `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way, and more generic way is to combine use `split`

As is mentioned in the OP, the user already mentions that he has two different field separators, but clearly states that the last field has a space as field-separator. This implies that one separator has precedence over the other. So, in this case, it would make sense to just perform an additional action on the last field.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS=" "}{n=split($NF,a," ")}
     { for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print $1,$2,$3,a[n] }' file
```

Here, the last field is split using a blank as field-separator. The total fields is saved in variable `n` which is used to loop over all possibilities.